# KiCad PCB: enlarging areas

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I am using KiCad 6.0 for PCB drawing. I want to enlarge the drawn area I marked, is it possible to do this, and how do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to zoom in?

Comment: No i want to zoom out, only 5 volts

Comment: Do you not know how to zoom out? I'm not really sure what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Ahhhh I see the blue drawing only now after staring at the image for 1 min... Select the track. Hit E. Type new trace width.

Comment: Do you mean you want to enlarge the track, or you want to enlarge the spacing around the track?

Comment: When ı select the track no new track width, there is enlarge the line, ı want to increase the distance (5volt-Gnd)

Comment: I want to enlarge the trace space around @Hearth

Comment: Is it the clearance spacing between the trace and ground that you want to increase?

Comment: You can define a new net class with wider track spacing and apply that net class to your route. But I’m not sure that’s what you’re after.

Comment: You could define a keep out and get rid of the ground plane entirely in that area, but I'm not sure there is any point given that you are working with 5V.

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to enlarge the trace space around*

One way you can do that is to apply copper "keep-out" areas around the particular track. You can shape the "keep-out" area just like you can make a complex shape for a copper pour. You can tell KiCAD to "keep-out" just the copper so that the track isn't affected by this action.

Comment: thank you very much, Ok.!

Comment: @MehmetEminARSLAN as a new user, welcome and, take note of the following: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You can also accept your own answer should you feel that my answer provided no help.

Answer (score 0):

By choosing keep out from the area I marked on the right, I achieved the result I wanted.  I removed the area I didn't want.

[image]

Comment: There is the option to add an additional "Keepout" area, as you've done, and carefully define what to keep out.  Then there is also the option to right click on the existing Zone and add a "Cutout" Area within that Zone, less parameters to define.

Comment: @Nedd I don't believe zone cutouts are an option in KiCad 6. They might have been added in the soon-to-be-released KiCad 7?